# Adding content to facebook feed from Android app

Tags: android, facebook

I made a little example for posting messages to facebook feed via Android app.
It works great but i just want to add more content to the post like the facebook page's icon, a link and more stuff..

How can i add these parameters to my facebook dialog to post them as well?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

   Facebook facebook = new Facebook("Here i got my app id.");

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // Posting my message, maybe here i could add paramterers like icon and a link etc..?
      facebook.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", new PostDialogListener());
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
   {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   }

 public abstract class BaseDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {


    e.printStackTrace();
}
@Override
public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }


  }

    public class PostDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
               ki("Message posted on the wall.");
            } else {
                ki("No message posted on the wall.");
            }
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void publishPhoto(String imageURL) {
    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "Post to Facebook!");

    try {

        JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
        attachment.put("message", Utils.s(R.string.fb_message));
        attachment.put("name", Utils.s(R.string.fb_name));
        attachment.put("href", Utils.s(R.string.url_dotzmag));
        attachment.put("description", Utils.s(R.string.fb_description));

        JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
        media.put("type", "image");
        media.put("src", imageURL);
        media.put("href", Utils.s(R.string.url_dotzmag));
        attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));

        JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject prop1 = new JSONObject();
        prop1.put("text", "Dotz App on Android Market");
        prop1.put("href", Utils.s(R.string.url_android_market));
        properties.put("Get the App for free", prop1);

        JSONObject prop2 = new JSONObject();
        prop2.put("text", "Dotz Tuning on Facebook");
        prop2.put("href", Utils.s(R.string.url_facebook_fanpage));
        properties.put("Visit our fanpage", prop2);

        attachment.put("properties", properties);

        Log.d("FACEBOOK", attachment.toString());

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
        mFacebook.dialog(mActivity, "stream.publish", params, new PostPhotoDialogListener());
        //mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(), null);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("FACEBOOK", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}
public class PostPhotoDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Successfully shared on Facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*
            mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());
            mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new Bundle(), "DELETE",
                            new WallPostDeleteListener(), null);
                }
            });
            */
        } else {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "No wall post made");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PostPhotoDialogListener cannot be resolved to a type,

How can i implement it please help me

Comment: You want to post using Dialog or without Dialog